# useEffect loop due to useSelector updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a useEffect

```
function Component () {
    const facets = useSelector(getFacets)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(search(facets, param2, param3))
    }, [dispatch, facets, param2, param3])
    
    //rest of component with return
}
```

now search will actually update that `facets`

```
//Inside my slice
const search = (facets, param2, param3) => async(dispatch) => {
   //do a fetch using param2 and param3
   //fetch comes back with a facets object
   //alter response facets object based on 'old' facets
   dispatch(setFacets(newFacets)) // set the new facets
}
```

The issue is, when this useEffect runs, the re-render causes `const facets = useSelector(getFacets)` to load a new value... Linting requires I have `facets` as a dependency in the `useEffect` but putting it there means it'll just loop over and over again. How do I stop it?

I've tried pulling the logic out of a useEffect and putting it in a useCallback, but again, linting requires that I put `facets` as a dependency, which is basically the same exact issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solved

---

Sooooo Redux has a few store methods; `dispatch` being one of them. For me, the store method I was looking for was [getState](https://redux.js.org/api/store#store-methods-1). More info [if you look here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic) and cmd/ctrl + F 'getState'

I didn't think I could access the state within my slice because React would not allow me to use `useSelector` within the slice for obvious reasons. What was not obvious to me at the time was that I could gain access with `getState`

#### So, the edited code would look like:

1. remove the `facets` param within the component because I won't need it anymore

```
function Component () {
    //const facets = useSelector(getFacets) --> NO LONGER NEEDED

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(search(/*facets, */param2, param3))
    }, [dispatch, /*facets, */param2, param3])
    
    //rest of component with return
}
```

2. edit the function within the slice, removing the `facets` param and including `getState` alongside `dispatch`

```
//Inside my slice
const search = (param2, param3) => async(dispatch, getState) => {
   //do a fetch using param2 and param3
   //fetch comes back with a facets object
   //grab 'old' facets using NEW getState and same selector: getFacets
   oldFacets = getFacets(getState())
   //alter response facets object based on oldFacets
   dispatch(setFacets(newFacets)) // set the new facets
}
```

#### Voila, no more infinite loop.